# Clickhouse return array of records?

Tags: clickhouse

Is it possible in click house to have a column return an array of objects?

I know groupArray can return a specific column, however I want to return all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ClickHouse can return array of data.

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    dt DateTime,
    ...
    arr Array(String)
) Engine=Memory()
```

If you want to return all columns in a table as an array, then all of the columns must have the same type since arrays need to have the same type of elements. Therefore the following will be valid:

```sql
CREATE TABLE array_of_all_columns(
    a String, 
    b String
) Engine=Memory
```

Then you can get all columns as an array:

```sql
SELECT array(*) as arr FROM array_of_all_columns;

┌─arr───────┐
│ ['A','B'] │
└───────────┘
┌─arr───────┐
│ ['C','D'] │
└───────────┘
```

In above example, if you have a 3rd column that is **not** a type of `String`, then you will get this error:

`DB::Exception: There is no supertype for types String, String, Int32 because some of them are String/FixedString and some of them are not: While processing [a, b, c].`

Comment: Thanks! So they all need to be the same type?

Comment: @YayoUK, yes, all columns need to have same type.